# Before and after pseudo elements on IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am working on this page: [link to page](http://montowniasmakuizdrowia.pl/).
Inside `h2` I have `before` and `after` elements. In IE they are too big, original width and height these images are not working. When I am trying to resolve this problem, in FF and Chrome everything is getting even worse.
In Edge things are a little bit different - I have figured out a way to make images smaller, but `before` element is inside `h2` text.
Here are the examples:
Normal (from FF and Chrome)
[image: normal view]
A little strange (from Edge)
[image: strange view]
So crazy (from IE)
[image: karuzela śmiechu]

CSS code:

```
h2{/*How I am displaying h2 elem */
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 45px auto 115px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}
h2::before {
    content: url(img/pepper.svg);
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
}
h2::after{
    content: url(img/apple.svg);    
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
}
@supports (-ms-accelerator:true) { /*Trying to resolve problem in Edge */
    h2::before {
        position: absolute;
    }
    h2::after{
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove h2 width  80% and try.

Comment: Oh, that was so simple, thank you! :) Also removing `supports` resolved problem in Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ankit says, removing `width: 80%` is doing right on IE. Also removing part with `supports` resolved problem with Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the positon of before and after leftmost and rightmost.
If it doesnt work,try making pixels to %.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (assuming you have control of the HTML): add an empty  right after the input, and target that in CSS using input+ span:after

```
.field_with_errors {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}
.field_with_errors input+span:after {
  content: "*"
}
<div class="field_with_errors">Label:</div>
<div class="field_with_errors">
  <input type="text" /><span></span> 
</div>
```

I'm using this approach in AngularJS because it will add .ng-invalid classes automatically to  form elements, and to the form, but not to the .